# Very slow Elastic Search Range Filter

Tags: elasticsearch

We a have a use case where we have added a new float field to our Elasticsearch index. The structure of the field is:

```
class Foo {
    Float x
    Float y
}
```

This is our filter query which uses the above field:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {
                    "boost": 1
                }
            },
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "foo.x": {
                        "gte": 3,
                        "lte": 5
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The response time for this query is about 500ms.

However we have another field in the index similar to the above:

```
class Bar {
    Float a
    Float b
}
```

Corresponding filter query for the same:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 5,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match_all": {
                    "boost": 1
                }
            },
            "filter": [{
                "range": {
                    "bar.a": {
                        "gte": 3,
                        "lte": 5
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

The response time for this field when tried with the above filter query is less than 50ms.
Our index size is roughly 100 million documents.

Full Index Mapping:

```
{
    "elastic_index_name": {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "foo": {
                    "properties": {
                        "x": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "y": {
                            "type": "float"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "bar": {
                    "properties": {
                        "a": {
                            "type": "float"
                        },
                        "b": {
                            "type": "float"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One difference between the two fields is that the first field (Foo) is present in too few documents (in magnitude of hundreds) as compared to the second field (Bar) is present in many documents (in the magnitude of ten thousand).

What I have tried so far:

1. Forcing merge the segments to see if query / node cache improves the latency of the first filter query.
2. Changed the datatype to float_range and then use it in the range query.

Both these approaches didn't seem to help improve the latency.

Another approach which I tried is to disable the fetch phase of Elastic Search Query by setting the request parameter _source=false in the elastic endpoint. Elastic endpoint:

```
https://<elastic_endpoint>/elastic_index_name/_search?_source=false
```

This made the first query very fast (less than 20ms) but unfortunately no metadata were returned.

As such can someone please provide insights as why there could be a difference in the response times for both these filters.